# How to change several texts on button click in android studio

Tags: android

HELP ME PLEASE! I want to create 2 buttons ("Next" and "Previous") that will change the text in TextView. I made a switch and "systemcounter" to change the cases, which then will set another text in TextView. When I test my program in this window buttons do not change the pages. I think this is because the system cannot see the "systemcounter"

````
    private Button next_button;
    private Button previous_button;
    private TextView Text_set1;
    int systemcounter = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_learningpage);

        next_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        previous_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
        Text_set1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text_set);

        next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                systemcounter = systemcounter + 1;
            }
        });
        previous_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                systemcounter = systemcounter - 1;

            }
        });

        switch (systemcounter) {
            case (0):
                Text_set1.setText("Thermodynamics is the branch of physics that deals with the relationships between heat and other forms of energy.");
                previous_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;

            case (1):
                Text_set1.setText("Hi there");
                previous_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case (2):
                Text_set1.setText("How are you");
                previous_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case (3):
                Text_set1.setText("How old are you?");
                break;

            default:
                Text_set1.setText("OPS");
                break;
        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have switch statement in oncreate method and so it executes it only once, make a seperate method like
setEditText(int systemcount)  and create your switch tehre and call this methods from button onclick methods

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setText() {
       switch (systemcounter) {
            case (0):
                Text_set1.setText("Thermodynamics is the branch of physics that deals with the relationships between heat and other forms of energy.");
                previous_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;

            case (1):
                Text_set1.setText("Hi there");
                previous_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case (2):
                Text_set1.setText("How are you");
                previous_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            case (3):
                Text_set1.setText("How old are you?");
                break;

            default:
                Text_set1.setText("OPS");
                break;
        }
}
```

and call this method in your *listeners* (like this)

```
next_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                systemcounter = systemcounter + 1;
                setText();
            }
        });
```